# Should I use BlazeDS for this?

Tags: flash, blazeds

I have a flash project that polls a php server every 10 seconds to check for commands. I have 1200 machines running this on a local network.

When we have network slowdowns, polling sometimes fails and the project hangs. Is Blaze/LiveCycle well behaved on thin networks? Is it more robust than polling under these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much the polling (or pushing) part that would make a BlazeDS better/faster. What would make it better (probably) is if you use BlazeDS and only send data when necessary, and only what is necessary -- thus limiting the overall traffic. It sounds like polling hangs because at some point in time you end up sending a lot of data and it takes Flex a while to injest that data.

I've run simulations with 8000 entities pushing state (an object with ~20 string fields and 2-3 large lists of strings) to Flex via BlazeDS and performance was OK.

Comment: Sounds promising. If I connect 1200 clients to a BlazeDS server, does it keep 1200 persistent connections open?

Comment: Im not 100% sure on that. I believe you get 1 pipe per "browser".

Answer (score 0):

You could also check [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org), which comes with a good, scalable and fault tolerant asynchronous servlets stack. It relies on long-polling and would provide a much more "real-time" experience than simple polling (though you don't necessarily need this in your application).

Using asynchronous servlets could solve some server-side scalability issues, but it wouldn't fix the possible client overloading issue pointed out by debracey.

You can see a short video about real-time messaging with GraniteDS [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRLZcU-m6G8).